# Illegal escape character netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, compiler-errors

I have a programming assignment which requires the code to be single line(shortest code). I did it, but for some reason, I get the error "Illegal Escape Character". Some people say claim that it will not do the same in eclipse. However, I have to turn in NetBeans project.

This is my code:

```
public class ShortestCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your email address").matches(".*@.*\..*") ? "Address Appears Valid" : "Address is Invalid");
    }
}
```

What can I do so it is acceptable by NetBeans IDE? All the error saying is "Illegal escape character." and does not provide with any other hints.

Comment: Problem is fixed, it was just as easy as adding one more backslash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This, this is the problem:

```
matches(".*@.*\..*")
```

I suspect you want a regular expression with exactly this pattern:

```
.*@.*\..*
```

But you're writing it as a Java string literal, so you need to escape the backslash:

```
matches(".*@.*\\..*")
```

The compiler is complaining because `\.` isn't a valid escape sequence.

Answer (score 1):

A single dot requires a double slash to escape the character

```
"Enter your email address").matches(".*@.*\\..*")
```